# Solution of a functional equation $f(x+y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

I am looking for a proof that the solution of the functional equation:

$$f(x+y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)$$

is:

$$f(z)=az+(b_1+b_2)$$
$$f_1(z)=az+b_1$$
$$f_2(z)=az+b_2$$

Assume that $x,y,z$ are real numbers, that the domain of $f$ is the real numbers, and that $f$ is continuous. Feel free to substitute some other domain/regularity assumption if they are necessary.

I am interested in this functional equation because it comes up in social choice theory. An accessible proof would be an advantage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the functions $f,f_1,f_2$ are all $C^0$. Then by setting $y=0, x=x$ and $x=0, y=y$

$$f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(0)~~,~~f(x)=f_1(0)+f_2(x)$$

We substitute back and after setting $g(x)=f(x)-f_1(0)-f_2(0)$ we see that it satisfies the well known functional relation

$$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$

Since $g$ is continuous, it can be shown using some standard manipulations (see some related tricks and results for reference in the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850534/solutions-of-fxyn-fxfyn?rq=1)) that $g(x)=ax$. Thus we conclude that with $f_{1,2}(0)=b_{1,2}$

$$f(x)=ax+b_1+b_2~~,~~f_1(x)=ax+b_1~~,~~ f_2(x)=ax+b_2$$

NOTE: If the functions are supposed to be $C^1$ showing this becomes trivial since we can rearrange the last equation, divide by $y$ and take the limit $y\to 0$

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}{y}=\lim_{ y\to 0} \frac{g(y)}{y}\Rightarrow g'(x)=g'(0)=a$$

which in turn implies that $g$ is linear, as above.